# Create dynamic imagebuttons in a while loop and fire their events without using gridview

Tags: c#, dynamic, while-loop, imagebutton

I'm trying to do these:

1. access my site's contents and read theme from my database
2. dynamically create a table without using grid-view and dynamically generate Image Buttons in
   it to edit and delete my contents.

I Succeed to define a Post Back URL for one of my image buttons and post it to a new page with my content ID to edit it but I failed to define an event and fire it for delete my content without going to a new page.

Here is my code :

```
var cn = new SqlConnection();
        var cmd = new SqlCommand();

        int i=0;

        try
        {
            using (cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnString"].ToString()))
            {
                cn.Open();
                using (cmd = new SqlCommand("ContentArchiveCategory", cn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CatID", txtCategories.SelectedValue);
                    var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);


                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        i++;

                        if (i % 2 != 0)
                        {
                            var tr = new TableRow();
                                tr.CssClass = "ADACLTOdd".ToString();

                                    var no = new TableCell();
                                        no.Text = i.ToString();
                                        no.CssClass = "ADACLTNoColumn".ToString();
                                    tr.Cells.Add(no);

                                    var date = new TableCell();
                                        date.Text = dr["DateCreated"].ToString();
                                        date.CssClass = "ADACLTDateColumn".ToString();
                                    tr.Cells.Add(date);

                                    var title = new TableCell();
                                        title.Text = dr["Title"].ToString();
                                        title.CssClass = "ADACLTTitleColumn".ToString();
                                    tr.Cells.Add(title);

                                    var edit = new TableCell();
                                        edit.CssClass = "ADACLTEditColumn".ToString();
                                            var ice = new ImageButton();
                                                ice.ImageUrl = "~/Images/ICSEdit.png".ToString();
                                                ice.PostBackUrl = "ContentEdit.aspx?id=" + dr["ContentID"].ToString();
                                                ice.ToolTip = "ویرایش".ToString();
                                        edit.Controls.Add(ice);
                                    tr.Cells.Add(edit);

                                    var delete = new TableCell();
                                        delete.CssClass = "ADACLTDeleteColumn".ToString();

                                            var icd = new ImageButton();
                                                icd.ImageUrl = "~/Images/ICSDelete.png".ToString();
                                                icd.ToolTip = "پاک".ToString();
                                                icd.ID = dr["ContentID"].ToString();
                                                icd.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(icd_Click);
                                        delete.Controls.Add(icd);
                                    tr.Cells.Add(delete);

                            ContentListTable.Rows.Add(tr);
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            var tr = new TableRow();
                                tr.CssClass = "ADACLTEven".ToString();

                                    var no = new TableCell();
                                        no.Text = i.ToString();
                                        no.CssClass = "ADACLTNoColumn".ToString();
                                    tr.Cells.Add(no);

                                    var date = new TableCell();
                                        date.Text = dr["DateCreated"].ToString();
                                        date.CssClass = "ADACLTDateColumn".ToString();
                                    tr.Cells.Add(date);

                                    var title = new TableCell();
                                        title.Text = dr["Title"].ToString();
                                        title.CssClass = "ADACLTTitleColumn".ToString();
                                    tr.Cells.Add(title);

                                    var edit = new TableCell();
                                        edit.CssClass = "ADACLTEditColumn".ToString();
                                            var ice = new ImageButton();
                                                ice.ImageUrl = "~/Images/ICSEdit.png".ToString();
                                                ice.PostBackUrl = "ContentEdit.aspx?id=" + dr["ContentID"].ToString();
                                                ice.ToolTip = "ویرایش".ToString();
                                        edit.Controls.Add(ice);
                                    tr.Cells.Add(edit);

                                    var delete = new TableCell();
                                        delete.CssClass = "ADACLTDeleteColumn".ToString();

                                            var icd = new ImageButton();
                                                icd.ImageUrl = "~/Images/ICSDelete.png".ToString();
                                                icd.ToolTip = "پاک".ToString();
                                                icd.ID = dr["ContentID"].ToString();
                                                icd.Click += icd_Click;
                                        delete.Controls.Add(icd);
                                    tr.Cells.Add(delete);

                            ContentListTable.Rows.Add(tr);
                        }

                        ContentListTable.Visible = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        catch
        {
            CatMessage.Visible = true;
            CatMessage.BorderColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#930000");
            CatMessage.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F4B7B7");

            CatMsg1.Text = string.Format("{0} عزیز! متاسفانه در برقراری ارتباط با سرور مشکلی پیش آمده، لطفاً این مورد را به مدیریت سایت گزارش کنید", Session["FirstName"]);
        }
    }
}


protected void icd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton icd = sender as ImageButton;
    CatMessage.Visible = true;
            CatMessage.BorderColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#930000");
            CatMessage.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F4B7B7");
            CatMsg1.Text = string.Format("{0}",icd.ID);
}
```

I tried both ways  `icd.Click += icd_Click;` and  `icd.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(icd_Click);` to fire my event but it didn't work at all.